# How to restore certificate in Android?

Tags: google-play

I have uploaded an app on Google Play, unfortunately I have lost certificate of the uploaded app but I have password of the app. Now I want to upload new version of the app but I have no certificate, is there any way to recover the certificate of the app and upload the newer version of the app. Please help me in this respect, your help would be  cordially appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you solved it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot recover the certificate if you lost it.

That's the point of the certificate, it behaves like a (private) key in real life. If you lose the key and its copies, then you have to change the lock.

Answer (score 1):

1)Generate new certificate:

keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias

2) Convert to .pem:

keytool -export -rfc -alias my-alias -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore my-release-key.jks

3) Send .pem to Contact Form:

[General issues - Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs)

it takes 2 busines days to answer but this is the way if you dont want to re publish your app ;)

then you can sign your apk as you do before

(for me)

zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk

ReadMore

[Manage your app signing keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible with `Google Play App Signing`

A short description

Users are installing apk with own google signing when you have uploaded previously with custom sign to google play

And if you didn't enable this feature there is an opportunity to take it now but with the help of google support team